# Vue: Can't iterate Object

Tags: vue.js

I have got following code:

```
            console.log("My Object is:");
            console.log(this.LoadedBaseMapLayersContent);

            for(obj of this.LoadedBaseMapLayersContent)
            {
            //  console.log(obj);
              console.log("can't get this string");
            }
```

I am checking if `this.LoadedBaseMapLayersContent` have data, and it's seems that it's have object inside, but it's have very strange type `[__ob__: Observer]`.

In console I see next:

```
My Object is:
[__ob__: Observer]
0: Array[1]
__ob__: Observerlength: 1
__proto__: Array
```

But I can't understand why my code do not get inside `for of` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Reactivity In Depth](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked)

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data
>   option, Vue.js will walk through all of its properties and convert
>   them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty. This is an
>   ES5-only and un-shimmable feature, which is why Vue.js doesn’t support
>   IE8 and below.
>
> The getter/setters are invisible to the user, but under the hood they
>   enable Vue.js to perform dependency-tracking and change-notification
>   when properties are accessed or modified.

You don't show what the data item looks like, but from the log, it appears you have something like this:

```
LoadedBaseMapLayersContent: {0: ['value']}
```

Which will not be iterable as an array.

Comment: thanks but why "can't get this string" is unreachable?

Comment: @user1432751 I don't think your data item is an array; I think it is an object with a numeric key that contains an array, so it can't be iterated using `for...of`

Comment: You can read vue object props and iterate over each object properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object props using Object.getOwnPropertyNames and pass current vue object, then iterate over each property.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted() {
        var self = this;
        var listOfProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.user);

        listOfProps.forEach(elementProp => console.log(objectProps[elementProp]));
    },
    data: {
        user: {
            name: 'dany',
            lastname: 'paredes'
        }
    }
})
```